# Посоветуйте генератор случайных RGBA векторов

Tags: qt, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Нужно генерировать цвета, как мы знаем цвет *RGBA* в *Qt* представлен как `unsigned int`, Нужен генератор отвечающий следующим требованиям:

- Генерирующий числа с большим разбросом друг от друга;
- Естественно, без повторений.

Comment: А вам точно RGB с рандомной прозрачностью нужен?

Comment: @gil9red это все исправимо

Answer (score 1):

Контролировать разброс и уникальность придется вручную. Приведу пример с уникальностью. С циклом нужно осторожнее – когда-нибудь закончатся все комбинации, поэтому, нужно будет или пересоздавать / очищать `unique`:

```
class UniqueRGB {
public:
    UniqueRGB() {
        qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());
    }

    QRgb get() {
        QRgb rgb;
        do {
            int r = rand() % 255;
            int g = rand() % 255;
            int b = rand() % 255;

            rgb = qRgba(r, g, b, 255);
        } while (unique.contains(rgb));

        unique.insert(rgb);

        return rgb;
    }

private:
    QSet<QRgb> unique;
};
```

Использование:

```
UniqueRGB uniqueRGB;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    QRgb rgb = uniqueRGB.get();
    qDebug() << rgb << QColor::fromRgb(rgb);
}
```

Comment: Я бы тоже такой сделал, но вот именно хранить unique, да еще и контролировать разброс самому циклами это не дзен, нужна математичееская функция, обеспечвающее это хотя бы, но я про такую не знаю.

Comment: @OlegUP, и как же? Комбинаций всех вариантов rgb конЕчно и не так много

Comment: говорю, же знать бы такое распределение, по его функции можно было бы создать нужный генератор, но я сам плохо Тер Вер учил.